# How to integrate some UI with different default layout together by javafx (tabpane, menebutton)?

Tags: java, javafx

As image shows: I use Scene Builder created a HBox in BorderPane Top.  HBox is including two types UI: MenuButton  and tabpane.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqaHd.jpg)

What’s current style is:    When I click tabpane, the tabpane will left a blank area under MenuButton , this area is unused in HBox.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RxDZ.jpg)

What my request is:  When I click the tabpan, the tabpane can use this area.  I find a good example:  EXCEL.   See the menubar of EXCEL.
The “ File “ is similar as my MenuButton (also has some difference, the excel “file” shows a pane when click it, my menubutton show a menulist), 
 and “ Start” ,”inset” is similar as my tabpane. 
If I explained not clear, please refer a EXCEL, WORD our OUTLOOK. 
Thanks.

How can I solve this?

1. Should I customize the UI of tabpane or menubutton?
2. If is there any other UI can realize this, which I just don’t know?
   Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your FXMLController:

```
// Tells the HBox to expand the tabPane whenever possible.
HBox.setHgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

// If invisible, menuButton will not take space on the screen
menuButton.managedProperty().bind(menuButton.visibleProperty());

// A click on the tabPane will make menuButton invisible, freeing room for the tabPane to take over the rest of the HBox
tabPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> menuButton.setVisible(false));
```